# HttpLoggingInterceptor not logging on android release builds

Tags: android, okhttp

I have an issue with the places API on the release build of my app and it would help me a lot if I could see the logs coming from the `OkHttpClient`. I am adding a `HttpLoggingInterceptor` to it, but I can only see the logs on debug builds. How can I see them on release builds?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please check your code, I think you have added like this thats why its happen

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {  
    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(Level.BODY);
    httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
}
```

or post your code here

Comment: ok, it was totally my fault, surprise surprise. The problem was that I added custom logging to the interceptor, which, DRUMROLL, was only working on debug. Thanks :)